# Azure DevOps Test Plan > Configurations page giving Page Not Found Error - known issue in ADO?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to access the Configurations section in ADO within the Test Plan area, and it's giving me a Page Not Found error 404 message. This is also happening on the Parameters page. Does anyone know if this is a known issue within ADO? Is there a work around to update and add configurations?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you do not have enough permissions to access Test Plans. You need to verify your [license](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/manual-test-permissions?view=azure-devops#license-requirements) and [role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/manual-test-permissions?view=azure-devops#access-by-user-role).

Azure Test Plans uses an access level called **Basic + Test Plans**.

**Stakeholders/Readers** have limited access to manual testing features. So if you were added as either of these roles, you will not be able to manage test plans and test suites, or test configurations and environments.

More details here:

- [Manual test permissions and access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/manual-test-permissions?view=azure-devops)
- [Default permissions and access for Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions-access?view=azure-devops#azure-test-plans)